# How to clear bits of unsigned char array in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Let's suppose I have `unsigned char` array called backup where I want to copy some bytes. But what I want to do is to clear most of the bits (18 bits from right to left). What I need to stay is the two bits on the left. This is my try:

```
memcpy (buf, " AA", 3);
unsigned char backup[3];
memcpy( backup, buf, 3 ); // backup
int two_bits_backup;
two_bits_backup = (int) backup &= ~0b001111111111111111111111;
```

But it generates error:
lvalue required as left operand of assignment

How to clear the two bits successfully?

What I want to do is to clear these bits (bold)

in case two_bits_backup = 0b11**1111111111111111111111**;

```
case two_bits_backup ==   0b110000000000000000000000;
```

I wanted to convert the unsigned char array to int and then to clear it.

I am using this on C and 32-bit platform, where int has 4 bytes.

Comment: If `backup` is an unsigned char array, you can't just treat it as if it's an `int`.  (in other words, `(int)backup` is very wrong and it's not doing anything like what you want.)

Comment: do you know, that  a&=b is short form for a = a & b? as the result you cannot modily (int)backup, because it is r-value

Comment: The `backup` in your code is not an `unsigned char *`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you provide sample input/output that demonstrates what you want?

Comment: I wanted to convert the unsigned string array to integer and then to clear the 22 bits

Comment: `backup` is an array. So `backup &= ~0b001111111111111111111111` makes no sense.

Comment: I see, I can use a loop to clear it.

Comment: No, I mean actual sample input/output, not just a vague English description. Also, which is it? 2 or 18 or 22 or 32 bits or what?

Comment: Why is that every time you say something, you make up a new number? First you said you want to "*clear most of the bits (18 bits from right to left)*". Then you commented, saying "*clear the 22 bits*". And now your latest comment says you want to "*Clear bit 23 and 24*", which is only 2.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, I messed it up completely. So the 23th and 24th bit should stay untouched, and the bits 22th-1th should be cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're getting is because you're attempting to assign a value to an array.  An array cannot be assigned to as a whole, even if you attempt to cast it.

You need to perform the bit clearing on each byte individually, then use bit shifting to put the individual bits into `two_bits_backup`

```
backup[0] &= ~0x3f;
backup[1] &= ~0xff;
backup[2] &= ~0xff;

two_bits_backup = backup[0] << 16;
two_bits_backup |= backup[1] << 8;
two_bits_backup |= backup[2];
```

Note that this assumes that the bytes in `backup` are most significant byte first with most significant bit first.

Comment: And don't forget to shift them into the right position to store them into the integer.

Comment: @AndreKampling Done

Comment: useless / possibly harmful casts.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right, the implicit conversion should take care of that.  Removed the casts.

Comment: @dbush unless the variable is not volatile, if it is then  to assign zero min 3 operations are needed (ARM gcc 6.3).

Comment: @PeterJ The above code works in the general case.  If it is later decided that different bits need to be cleared, the only change is to the bitmask.  Also, what you're talking about is a micro-optimization.  Better to have code that is clearer to the reader and leave the optimizations to the compiler, and only optimize when benchmarks say you should.

Comment: @dbush assignments do not work in the general case in your opinion. It is just a bad poor code. In thiscase `&= 0xff;` should be replaced with `=0;' and the last two lines removed at all (as shifting and OR-ing zeros do not change the value of the ORed number). If you use it on the volatile variables (especially 8 bit systems like AVR) you will get massive overhead.

Comment: @dbush: Could you please note in your answer that you assume the byte order to be most significant byte first, and the bit order most significant bit first?

Answer (score 1):

the other way is to use backup a a pointer to int:

```
two_bits_backup = *(int*)backup &= ~0b001111111111111111111111;
```

based on the comments below, I am adding this note: the backup must be of size [4] (or more) to work properly on most systems without violation of aliasing rules.

```
char backup[4];
or 
char *backup = malloc(4);
```

memcpy still can work, as prviously with  n= 3. The '&' operation will take care of possible trash in the upper byte.

Comment: No good.  `backup` has only 3 bytes, and an `int` is 4 bytes on OP's platform.  This writes past the end of the array, resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: No.  That violates strict aliasing and is a good way to get a `SIGBUS` or other failure on systems that have stricter alignment restrictions than x86 does.  Just because it "works" on an x86 platform doesn't mean it's not invalid C code.

Comment: You right. Size of  '4' of the backup is needed to work ok on most systems though.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you want to do exactly.Unsigned char is 1 byte.So You should make logical AND with 1100 0000 and shifting 6 bits right if you want to extract first 2 bits.

```
(backup[0] &= C0)>>6
```

The same way for all of the elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a char array to manage a 24 bits integer, you may operate in this way (for little endian machine). But, IMHO, it's not a clean way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char buf[3];

    // Backup should be sizeof(unsigned int) bytes because an int of 3 bytes doesn't exist!
    unsigned char backup[sizeof(unsigned int)];
    unsigned int two_bits_backup;

    memcpy (buf, " AA", sizeof(buf));
    // memset (buf, 0xD5, sizeof(buf));

    memset( backup, 0, sizeof(unsigned int));
    memcpy( backup, buf, sizeof(buf) ); // backup

    printf("%08X\n",*(unsigned int *)(backup));

    two_bits_backup = *(unsigned int *)(backup) &= ~0b001111111111111111111111;

    printf("%08X\n",two_bits_backup);

    return 0;
}
```